# How to make my fragment fit between my toolbar and bottom navigation bar and still make it scrollable?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I will have my main-activity layout file below so you can understand what is happening

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@menu/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav">
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#39b54a"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled">
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem with this layout is that the toolbar on the top and the bottom navigation bar cover content from my fragments. Also one of my fragments has got a recyclerview with many items and I can´t scroll down for some reason ? Is there a way to make the fragments fit exactly between the toolbar and bottomnavigation like resizing itself to fit into that area without cutting content and still make it scrollable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>  <!--include your layout file here -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav">
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#39b54a"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled">
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And by the way, you are supposed to set a layout resource file into the toolbar layout while including but you are passing the menu resource file. Change that also accordingly...

Comment: is there a problem with saving that file in the menu folder ?

Comment: @GoldNerd to keep things clean I would recommend you to keep all layout files in layout only... I am not sure if it throws error